# sh Job container after it is stopped

Tags: shell, kubernetes, containers

I am backuping my Postgresql database using this cronjob:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: postgres-backup
spec:
  schedule: "0 2 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: postgres-backup
            image: postgres:10.4
            command: ["/bin/sh"]
            args: ["-c", 'echo "$PGPASS" > /root/.pgpass && chmod 600 /root/.pgpass && pg_dump -Fc -h <host> -U <user> <db> > /var/backups/backup.dump']
            env:
            - name: PGPASS
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: pgpass
                  key: pgpass
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/backups
              name: postgres-backup-storage
          restartPolicy: Never
          volumes:
          - name: postgres-backup-storage
            hostPath:
              path: /var/volumes/postgres-backups
              type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

The cronjob gets successfully executed, the backup is made and saved in the container of the Job but this container is stopped after successful execution of the script.
of course I want to access the backup files in the container but I can't because it is stopped/terminated.

is there a way to execute shell commands in a container after it is terminated, so I can access the backup files saved in the container?

I know that I could do that on the node, but I don't have the permission to access it.

Comment: create another container and map the directory as hostpath and access it ?

Comment: that's all I needed, an idea - it works! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@confused genius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3638081/confused-genius) gave me a great idea to create another same container to access the dump files so this is the solution that works:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: postgres-backup
spec:
  schedule: "0 2 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: postgres-backup
            image: postgres:10.4
            command: ["/bin/sh"]
            args: ["-c", 'echo "$PGPASS" > /root/.pgpass && chmod 600 /root/.pgpass && pg_dump -Fc -h <host> -U <user> <db> > /var/backups/backup.dump']
            env:
            - name: PGPASS
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: dev-pgpass
                  key: pgpass
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/backups
              name: postgres-backup-storage
          - name: postgres-restore
            image: postgres:10.4
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/backups
              name: postgres-backup-storage
          restartPolicy: Never
          volumes:
          - name: postgres-backup-storage
            hostPath:
            # Ensure the file directory is created.
              path: /var/volumes/postgres-backups
              type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

after that one just needs to sh into the "postgres-restore" container and access the dump files.

thanks